# Assigning to property of type `UIView` has no effect

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiview

*I'm using Xcode 10.0 beta 6, so this might just be a bug.*

---

I'm experiencing a problem, where assigning a new `UIView`-instance to a property, does not seem to have any effect on the property.

Said property is `leadingView` in `ViewTextFieldCell`:

```
class ViewTextFieldCell: UITableViewCell {

   // ...

   var leadingView = UIView()

   // ...
}
```

When modifying an instance of the cell in the following way...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
   let cell = ViewTextFieldCell(style: .default, reuseIdentifier: "TestCell")

   cell.leadingView.backgroundColor = .blue

   let otherView = UIView()
   otherView.backgroundColor = .green
   cell.leadingView = otherView

   return cell
}
```

... the only change that is retained is the setting of the background color to blue.
It seems that the assignment of `otherView` has no effect.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from your example what other initialization happens to "leadingView", but the replacement "otherView" is not being added as a subview to the cell, nor does it have a frame or constraints.

Comment: I was assuming that the auto layout constraints associated with the view were bound to the property, not the `UIView`-instance; which is of course wrong. Updating the layout in a `didSet` for `leadingView` fixed the problem.